# Немного о стразах

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

Читаю тут инструкцию к набору для рукоделия. И там в перечне предметов, входящих в набор, есть "блюдце для страз". И, надо сказать, такую форму встречаю уже не первый раз.
И вот тут у меня возник вопрос: если много - стразы, то как будет один? Я всегда считала, что это слово мужского рода. То есть, один - страз. Но тогда блюдце должно быть для стразов. А если оно для страз, то это слово женского рода.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оно на самом деле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuchoin Kazuki, есть два варианта этого слова. Страз и страза (в им. ед.)
Первое фиксируется всеми словарями, второе - только некоторыми, не самыми авторитетными по части офроэпии, но тем не менее.

Первое порождает в род. мн. - стразов, второе - страз.
Соответственно, тут надо разбирать вопрос, насколько нормативна форма женского рода вообще, а не один конкретный падеж. Пока этот вопрос не закрыт, нет причин запрещать женский род и форму "[блюдце для] страз". Посмотрим, что будет дальше, язык должен сам выбрать какую-то одну форму.

Answer (score 3):

Стразы называются по фамилии изобретателя. Нет оснований употреблять это слово в женском роде. В единственном числе приемлемо: страз, стразик. Мн.число родительного падежа формируется по аналогии со словом "глаз". Один глаз, один страз, место для глаз, место для страз. Ведь мы же не говорим много "глазов".

Comment: >Стразы называются по фамилии изобретателя.  
  
И что с того?

Answer (score 1):

В орфографическом словаре под редакцией Лопатина указаны два варианта: страз, -а и страз***а,*** -ы

Answer (score 1):

Если считать, что страза - ж.род, то нулевое окончание в форе Р.п. мн.ч. "страз" является основным.

Если считать, что страз - м.р., то нулевое окончание также возможно, но оно является вариантным. Сравнить: один раз - много раз.